# ajax form on press enter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**//UPDATE**

```
$('#codice_prodotto').on('keyup', function(e) {
     if (e.which === 13) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#cerca_prodotto').trigger('click');
     }
});
```

this work in real time, but if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the script redirect me in domain/?codice_prodotto=val

Any solutions?

**//END UPDATE**

I have problems with ajax request, this is the index page:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#cerca_prodotto").click(function(){
    var dati = $("#form-cerca-prod").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "product/show_prod.php",
        data: dati,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){ $("#risultato").html(msg); },
        error: function(){ alert("Ricerca fallita, riprovare..."); }
    });
});
});
</script>
<form id="form-cerca-prod">
   <input name="codice_prodotto" type="text" placeholder="Codice Prodotto" id="codice_prodotto">
   <br><br>
   <input type="button" id="cerca_prodotto" value="Cerca">
</form>

<div id="risultato">
</div>
```

And this product/show_prod.php

```
    <?php
include "../config/config.inc.php";
$cod=urldecode($_POST['codice_prodotto']);
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prodotto WHERE id='$cod'");
if(mysql_num_rows($q)<1)
    echo "Nessun prodotto trovato!";
else{
    $p_id=mysql_result($q,0,"id");
    $p_descr=mysql_result($q,0,"descrizione");
    $p_prezzo=mysql_result($q,0,"prezzo");
    $p_prezzo=number_format($p_prezzo,2,',','.');
    ?>
    <br><br>
    <div style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9; padding: 6px; border-radius: 5px;">
        <table border="0" align="center" style="color: #fff;">
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Codice :
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <b><? echo $p_id; ?></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Nome :
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <code><? echo $p_descr; ?></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Prezzo :
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <b>&euro; <? echo $p_prezzo; ?></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2" style="padding: 7px;">
                    Quantit&agrave;: <input type="number" min="6" value="6" name="quantita" style="width: 40px;"><br><button type="submit" id="agg_prodotto"><img src="img/cart.png"> Aggiungi al carrello</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?
}
?>
```

if I click on the button, the script works! if I enter a code and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the keyboard the script not work!

How I can solve this?

Comment: I solved it by adding in form " onSubmit='return false;' "

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#codice_prodotto').on('keyup', function(e) {
     if (e.which === 13) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#cerca_prodotto').trigger('click');
     }
});
```

Comment: This will break if the form ends up having a `<textarea>`

Comment: @f.ardelian - This is based on the code in the question, it doesn't work with other elements as it's targeting the only input element in the code by ID, so even another input will break it, or anything else really, but that doesn't matter as it solves the OP's issue and is the easiest fix for the posted code. What could have been, should have been, might be etc. doesn't really matter.

Comment: this work in real time, but if I press enter the script redirect me in domain/?codice_prodotto=val

Comment: @user2078421 - That can be solved, edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your form:

```
<input type="submit" />
```

That's what triggers the automatic submit on enter.

Comment: A while ago I played with this and it wouldn't work if the submit button was hidden, so you can't use `display:none`. You'll have to hack your way out of this with absolute positioning outside of the screen (something like top:-10,left:-10,width:1,height:1,overflow:hidden,position:absolute)

Comment: @f.ardelian you could use `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: Yes, but in that case you'll have to keep in mind that the element will still use space in your layout.

Comment: And to whoever downvoted this (I had it at 1, now it's at 0), this is the best way to solve the problem. It makes more sense to have a submit button as part of your form than to use JavaScript when it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Because your form isn't submitting to any url. You can bind Enter key to trigger the AJAX request too. Just like the click event.

Answer (score 0):

I believe changing your script to this should work:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#cerca_prodotto").click(function(){
    var dati = $("#form-cerca-prod").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "product/show_prod.php",
        data: dati,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){ $("#risultato").html(msg); },
        error: function(){ alert("Ricerca fallita, riprovare..."); }
    });
});
$("#codice_prodotto").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#cerca_prodotto").click();
    }
});
});
```